# Plural forms in translations of Flex programs

Tags: apache-flex, internationalization

I want to support plural forms in translations of my Flex program properly like is possible [with Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq19-plurals.html), [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/sl/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nPluralForms.html) and [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Plural-forms).

Is there a (open source) library that handles this for Flex?

Comment: Reviewing the links you provide; it sounds like just an encapsulated condition. I don't know of any existing libraries to help with this. but I bet you could write something like this in an hour or less and release it as a project at riaforge.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good idea to use gettext format. You have two options:

- [AsGettext](http://code.google.com/p/asgettext/) is licensed as LGPL so it should be ok for any project.
- [as3-gettext](https://github.com/vincent-petithory/as3-gettext)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any additional libraries. Use standard Flex ResourceManager. In text resources define plural forms like that:

```
minute=minute, minutes
```

In this case, when you later ask for a such resource as

```
resourceManager.getStringArray('BundleName', 'minute')
```

you get the array of plural values like

```
[ 'minute', 'minutes' ]
```

Then use smth like

```
function getPlural(value:Number, plurals:Array):String
{
    if (ResourceManager.getInstance().localeChain[0] == 'en_US')
        if (value == 1) return plurals[0] else return plurals[1];
}
```

to select the right text for current locale. You can define this function directly in some package to be common for all classes. Unfortunately, you can not avoid such function because the plural rules of many languages are differ. For Russian, for example, the expression will be much more complicated and will take three plural word forms.
By the way, this method is very similar to how gettext works.

Comment: Very interesting. How do you escape comma's if you need them in the actual text ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Unfortunately it's impossible. If you look into the getStringArray() method source you will see simple `var array:Array = String(value).split(",")` usage. The only way I see is to override this method in ResourceManagerImpl somehow but I never seen such usecases in real.